Providing custom arguments to Azure Container Apps Job works in the portal, but not via Azure CLI with --args or --command
I have an Azure Container Apps Job that requires a custom argument for each run (a request ID telling the container which request to process).
If I open the job in the portal, go to Containers -> Edit and enter the command under "Command override", that works fine. But the custom command is then applied to every run of that job, whereas I need to provide a different request ID for each run.
I found the --args and --command parameters for az containerapp job start and I think they are what I'm looking for, but I can't get them to work. The difference between the two parameters is not clear to me from the documentation, so I've tried multiple combinations.

Configure Dockerfile with ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"] and run
az containerapp job start -n <job> -g <rg> --command "my_argument"
Configure Dockerfile with ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"] and run
az containerapp job start -n <job> -g <rg> --args "my_argument"
Configure Dockerfile with CMD ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"] and run
az containerapp job start -n <job> -g <rg> --command "dotnet" "MyApp.dll" "my_argument"
Configure Dockerfile with CMD ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"] and run
az containerapp job start -n <job> -g <rg> --args "dotnet" "MyApp.dll" "my_argument"

In none of these combinations did my application recognize any command line arguments. It works fine if I run the container locally with ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"] and docker run <image> my_argument.
I'm aware that I could use event triggers with a queue instead, but I'd like to understand why this is not working.

Did you ever figure this out? Facing the same issue.

Experimented a bit and it seems that --command and --args are completely ignored when using with az containerapp job start.
However they can be used with az containerapp job update to configure these fields and subsequently the start command will use those configured properties.
created an issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/1360

Yep, that works, but it's not a viable workaround as it makes parallel job executions pretty much impossible. Thanks for opening the issue.

In order to use --args command correctly in Azure CLI for Azure container app job, Make sure you are using correct syntax.
I have tried using the below command for container app  job and it worked successfully:-
Command Reference
az containerapp job start -n siliccontnerappjob -g rg-sample --command "dotnet MyApp.dll my_argument"

Output:-


The command does not throw any errors, but have you checked if the argument is actually passed to MyApp.dll? In my case it isn't. I'm not sure what you mean by using the correct syntax - what's wrong with mine?

It looks like you need to specify a few more arguments to the CLI to get it to understand this is a new run. I tried this:
az containerapp job start 
--name <> 
--resource-group <> 
--cpu 8 
--memory 32 
--image <>:latest 
--args "One" "Two" "Three"
From what I found, you must also specify the CPU and memory or its going to create a single run with very low resources. I am unsure what else might be not quite right (as in the replica timeout) as you can't set all the config options using the CLI. This did seem to trigger the job, with the overrides correctly though, so good luck!

I haven't verified this, but it seems to be in line with how the REST API works (where it's actually documented correctly). Still, the behavior doesn't make any sense - parameters like the image and CPU should be taken from the default configuration if omitted in the request.
